# VAAPI support on intel Elkhart Lake plateform

Tags: drivers, intel-graphics

We refer https://github.com/intel/media-driver/tree/intel-media-21.2.3 to build intel media driver and installed on ubuntu 21.04 then tested by vainfo, however we received below error message:

```
libva info: VA-API version 1.12.0
libva info: User environment variable requested driver 'iHD'
libva info: Trying to open /usr/local/lib/dri/iHD_drv_video.so
libva info: Found init function __vaDriverInit_1_12
libva error: /usr/local/lib/dri/iHD_drv_video.so init failed
libva info: va_openDriver() returns 2
vaInitialize failed with error code 2 (resource allocation failed),exit
```

Please advise and guide us how to resolve this issue, thank you.

Comment: Having driver in /usr/local/lib/dri/iHD_drv_video.so looks strange.

Comment: Hi N0rbert, I had tried install intel media driver on old platform and get vainfo result and it says 
**libva info: Trying to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/iHD_drv_video.so**
do you mean I had put driver in wrong location?

Comment: Yes, /usr/local/lib is wrong location, it will cause unpredictable behavior.

Comment: Hi N0rbert, thanks for your help, we will try again.