# When is Elkhart Lake support coming to Ubuntu?

Tags: support

When can we expect to see any support for Elkhart Lake from Ubuntu?

Answer (score 3):

What Elkhart Lake is

> the newest embedded silicon from Intel with a focus on IoT features to power the next generation of edge devices

Latest status from Canonical about Elkhart Lake: `... more details in the coming week...`

> "... Canonical is working closely with Intel to provide developers and enterprises with access to the latest features on Ubuntu platforms and expect to provide **more details in the coming week**..." - https://ubuntu.com/engage/iot-elkhart-lake

**Further Reading**

---

- https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/products/platforms/details/elkhart-lake.html
- [VAAPI support on intel Elkhart Lake plateform](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1361093/vaapi-support-on-intel-elkhart-lake-plateform)
- https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/elkhart-lake/21775
- https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=Intel-Elkart-Lake-DRM-Enable